# If string statement: What am I missing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, comparison

I've created a simple code which looks like this:

```
name = str(input ("What is your name?"))

gender = str(input ("What is your gender?"))

if gender == 'male' or 'Male':

    print ("Hello Mr %s" % (name))

elif gender == 'female' or 'Female':

    print ("Hello Mrs %s" % (name))

else:

    print ('Invalid gender. Please try again.')
```

However, no matter what gender I type (even random words like `test`), it always prints out the if statement, which means it satisfy the `gender == male` portion. Like if I key in `female`, the if statements still prints out. What am I missing here?

Comment: `name = str(input ("What is your gender?"))` you never assign gender?

Comment: sorry! that was a typo, I changed that to gender already! but still having the same issue.

Comment: If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 4):

### In steps

Use the right variable name first:

```
gender = input("What is your gender?")
```

Second, the use of `or` is wrong:

```
>>> 'male' or 'Male'
'male'
```

Use:

```
if gender == 'male' or gender == 'Male':
```

Alternatively use:

```
if gender.lower() == 'male':
```

### Whole program

```
name = input("What is your name?")
gender = input("What is your gender?")

if gender.lower() == 'male':
    print("Your are %s" % (gender))
elif gender.lower() == 'female':
    print("Your are %s" % (gender))
else:
    print('Invalid gender. Please try again.')
```

### Shorter version

```
name = input("What is your name?")
gender = input("What is your gender?")

if gender.lower() in ('male', 'female'):
    print("Your are %s" % (gender.lower()))
else:
    print('Invalid gender. Please try again.')
```

Comment: @Lafexlos Thanks. Just seen this. Added to my answer.

Comment: OMG! Solved it! Thank you! So actually what was the main problem in the program? Is it the use of or?

Comment: Another nice alternative (not useful in this case, but worth learning): `if gender in ('male', 'Male'):`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Can actually be useful here. See my shorter version.

Comment: @MikeMüller just to note - those `str` calls around `input` are redundant - `input` already returns a string

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for hint. Removed. Was a copy-paste problem.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing to more than one string, you need to do it differently:

```
if gender == 'male' or gender == 'Male':
```

Or, more simply:

```
if gender in ['male', 'Male']:
```

Or with a set:

```
if gender in {'male', 'Male'}:
```

Not much difference in speed with only two items, but with a lot of
items a set will be faster because it uses a hash table, while the list
uses linear search.

Now, as for what is happening with your code. If you do this:

```
if gender == 'male' or 'Male':
```

you are saying:

```
if (gender == 'male') or ('Male'):
```

So, no matter what `gender` is, if the first comparison is `False`, it
will just go on to `'Male'`. That is a non-empty string, so it’s always
`True` and the conditional always ends up `True` as well.

Comment: It's true that a set allows average O(1) lookup, but you still have to build the has table in O(n) time. You will need *lots* of items to see a difference, and even in that case, you'd better store the set as a global variable, so that the function does not need to re-build the set every time it is called

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I was thinking in terms of a use case where you build up the list dynamically, as in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462389/34462503#34462503).